# Meteor Email Template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to send an html email on Server side this is what I am following

1. `meteor add blaze`.
2. Client side:

---

```
var dataContext = {
    from: "wrs@mw.com",
    to: event.speakers[i].email,
    name: event.speakers[i].fname + " " + event.speakers[i].lname,
    subject: "Invitation to Event <h3>" + event.title + " !",
    message: "You must see this, it's amazing !",
    url: "http://myapp.com/content/amazingstuff"
};

Meteor.call('sendInvitationEmail', dataContext);
```

3. Server side:

---

```
Meteor.methods({
    sendInvitationEmail: function(subject, data) {
        var html = Blaze.toHTML(Blaze.With(data, function() {
            return Template.invitation;
        }));
        Email.send({
            to: data.to,
            from: data.from,
            subject: data.subject,
            html: html
        });
    }
});
```

4. Server template:

---

```
<template name="invitation">
   Hello {{name}},
   {{title}}
   {{message}}
   {{url}}
</template>
```

I am getting an error:

> "Error invoking Method 'sendInvitationEmail': Internal server error [500]"

Comment: Please take a look at the server side console and add the error description to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
meteor add cmather:handlebars-server
```

After installing this package you will have access to your template on server, like:

```
html = Handlebars.templates.invitation(data)
```

More docs available in [official repository](https://github.com/cmather/meteor-handlebars-server)

Answer (score 0):

Server-side rendering can be provided by the excellent [meteorhacks:ssr](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/ssr) package